# How to import CSV file as NumPy array?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Say I have a CSV file.csv in this format:

```
dfaefew,432,1
vzcxvvz,300,1
ewrwefd,432,0
```

How to import the second column as a NumPy array and the third column as another one like this:

```
second = np.array([432, 300, 432])
third = np.array([1, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`numpy.genfromtxt()` is the best thing to use here

```
import numpy as np
csv = np.genfromtxt ('file.csv', delimiter=",")
second = csv[:,1]
third = csv[:,2]

>>> second
Out[1]: array([ 432.,  300.,  432.])

>>> third
Out[2]: array([ 1.,  1.,  0.])
```

Comment: genfromtxt works better than loadtxt in my use case and I had to add dtype=None since my data had a mix of data types that I was reading. Just FYI....

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
In [15]: !cat data.csv
dfaefew,432,1
vzcxvvz,300,1
ewrwefd,432,0

In [16]: second, third = loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2), unpack=True, dtype=int)

In [17]: second
Out[17]: array([432, 300, 432])

In [18]: third
Out[18]: array([1, 1, 0])
```

Or [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```
In [19]: second, third = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2), unpack=True, dtype=None)
```

The only change in the arguments is that I used `dtype=None`, which tells `genfromtxt` to infer the data type from the values that it finds in the file.