# How to create numpy array of arrays from CSV?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I'm trying to get a Numpy array of arrays from a csv file
Each row is meant to be an independent mumpy array within the general array.
(relevant column names are 1,2,3....136).

I've tried this approach but I don't think it's the right way:

```
with open('faces_new.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    facesreader = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'))
    main_array = np.array()
    for row in facesreader:
        #create new array inside the main array
        local_array = np.array()
        for n in range(136):
            local_array = np.append(float(row[str(n)]))
            #add n to the array
        main_array = np.append(local_array)
    print(main_array)
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy? and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614749/how-to-import-csv-file-as-numpy-array-in-python/25614793?

Comment: Yes, they are using a different data structure than mine.
While I'm only using certain columns (1,2,3...136), they are using all of them, and each row is on a separate array, they are using all data.

Comment: Have you tried first doing normal list and then numpy.array()? Like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31250215/9513536

Comment: Definitely not the right way.  `np.array()` raises an error.  The use of `np.append` is all wrong too.  But if you insist on working this way, stick with list and list append.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` works with normal `csv` files.  If there's something unusual about your file you need to give us a sample.