# Calculate the mode of a numpy array for n elements

Tags: python, arrays

I want to calculate the mode of a big numpy array for every 16 elements in the array. I saved the array in a csv file. I opened the file and for every 16 elements, I want to calculate the mode and save the result in another file. If there are no more than 16 elements, I want to perform majority voting anyway. I uploaded the file of predictions. I tried this code below

Thank you

```
import csv
from scipy.stats import mode
import numpy as np

with open("prediction-pairs-overall.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for i in readCSV:
        values,counts = np.unique(readCSV, return_counts=True)   
        index = np.argmax(counts)  ##maximum values



        mode=values[index]
        print(mode)
        #input()
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there a particular problem with the code you've shown?

Comment: I want to calculate the mode for every 16 elements of a big array and save it in an another file (as a majority voting). I tried the above code but it does not work, there are some errors in the code

Comment: What are the errors? Why don't you remove them so that your code will work?

Comment: If I print the mode, I cant see the values of mode for the first 16 elements

Comment: What can you see instead?

Comment: My predictions are splitted in 16 blocks for an image. I want to merge all the 16 blocks and predict for a whole image using majority voting (mode)

Comment: <_csv.reader object at 0x7fd7e27d16d0>

Comment: I see this when I print the mode

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614749/how-to-import-csv-file-as-numpy-array-in-python

Comment: You are importing `mode` from scipy.stats but then you are declaring `mode` variable, making it useless.  Did you read [mode manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate `unique(i)` instead of `unique(readCSV)`.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open("prediction-pairs-overall.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i in readCSV:
        values, counts = np.unique(i, return_counts=True)   
        index = np.argmax(counts)  ##maximum values

        mode = values[index]
        print(mode)
```